# how to pause youtubevideo playing inside app?

Tags: ios, video, youtube

Hi I'm using  XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer to play the youtube video inside my app everything works fine. The problem is after navigating to next VC video is still playing how to pause or stop that video.

My code to play .

```
UIView *videoContainerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:videoContainerView];
    XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:vd];
    // NSLog(@"%@",inVideosObj.video);
    [videoPlayerViewController presentInView:videoContainerView];
    [videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

My code to pause.

```
 XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:vd];

 [videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer pause];
```

I have used this above code to pause the video its not working please help me i have been stuck here for long time .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController`. Instead, you should store your `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController` instance in a property when you first create it and use this one when you need to stop the video. See [DemoInlineViewController.m](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/blob/2.0.2/XCDYouTubeKit%20Demo/iOS%20Demo/DemoInlineViewController.m) from the demo project for a concrete example.